how to render external .msg files using react similar to we have react-doc-viewer for docs file
I want to write a code using react+typescript which reads '.msg' files stored in cosmosdb.
We will be getting the external url for the files using API response.
Now I want to render this external url(.msg) files using react.
I am looking a package similar to we have react-doc-viewer to render external url docs file.
The application is built in react+typescript using vite.

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.
